# Replace ID from json entity with random number without creating entity class

Tags: c#

I have testdata.json with object like this:

```
 "Entity": {
    "ID": "1",
    "name": "some name",
    "City": "some city",
    "address": "some address"
  }
```

Here are my 2 methods for withdrawing and deserializing this entity:

```
public static string ReadSettings(string name)
        {
            var parts = name.Split('.', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            JObject jObj = GetObject();
            foreach (var part in parts)
            {
                var token = jObj[part];
                if (token == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                else
                {
                    return token.ToString();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }


        private static JObject GetObject()
        {
            if (_jObject != null)
            {
                return _jObject;
            }

            var filename = Path.Combine(
                Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)!,
                "testdata.json");
            var json = File.ReadAllText(filename);

            _jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

            return _jObject;
        }
```

My question is next: is there any way I can replace Entity.ID with random number (I need this in tests, where I create new Entity - every time test runs - there should be new Entity with new unique ID)?
p.s. I'm just learning C# so don't judge me hardly if it's simple question =)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the given testdata.json content is not the real thing since running `JObject.Parse()` on it gives an exception. However, you can navigate to a property with the string key indexer of the `JObject` class and change it as:

```
// Generate a new random value.
var random = new Random();
var randomValue = random.Next(minValue, maxValue);

// Navigate to the property and assign the random value as a string.
_jObject["Entity"]["ID"] = randomValue.ToString();
```

The property navigation of course needs to match the structure of your Json.